# Assigning memory dynamically or on the stack based on a condition (if statement)

Tags: c, memory

I have a C program in which an array of floats has its elements accessed quite often for the duration of the program. The size of the array depends on an argument that a user will input and therefore will vary. Generally, the size will be small enough (~ 125 elements) so that the memory of the array can be placed on the stack and thus allocation and accessing it will be faster. But in rare cases, the array may be large enough such that it requires dynamic allocation. My initial solution for this was the following:

```
if(size < threshold){

    float average[size];
}
else{
    float *average;
    average = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * size ); 
}

// Do some stuff with average
```

This gives an error at compile time. How does one address such a problem?

Comment: `this gives an error at compile time`...what exactly?

Comment: The most obvious problem is that `average` is only in the scope of the `if/else`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh of course it is if the comment `Do some stuff with average` is accurate

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour ugh...missed that completely....right you are..

Comment: @SouravGhosh Here is the error: 
ONLM_Mod.c:275:66: error: use of undeclared identifier 'average'

Comment: @Haider yup, basically what Shafik said

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour your comment speaks for yourself. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of `average` has a limited lifetime in your code; it lives up to the end of the block. In other words, the way you declare `average` makes it available only inside the `if/else` block.

I suggest splitting this up in two functions: one handles the allocation; the other does the work. Something like this:

```
void do_average(int size, int threshold) {
    if (size < threshold) {
         float avg[size];
         average(size, avg);
    } else {
         float *avg = malloc(sizeof(*avg)*size);
         assert(avg != NULL);
         average(size, avg);
         free(avg);
    }
} 

void average(int avg_size, float avg[static avg_size]) {
    /* Do some stuff with avg */
}
```

You may want to think about how to handle the (unlikely) event of `malloc()` returning `NULL`. `assert()` might not be the better choice. I just put it there to make sure you don't forget to check for the error.

**NOTE**: As mentioned in the comments, this is a good opportunity to use VLA parameter declaration.

Comment: This might be a nice opportunity to use the rarely-seen variable-length-array-parameter declaration: `void do_average(int avg_size, float avg[static avg_size])` (see C11 6.7.6.3). I'm not sure the compiler *has* to error out if `avg` is accessed out of bounds, but it provides it more information about your intentions, and could help it check or optimize the code.

Comment: @Leushenko Hah, that's a nice point! Thanks for the insight. Updated the code. There is no bounds checking, but indeed, it does provide more information to someone reading the code.

Comment: @Felipe Goncalves Your answer works. What also works is declaring a pointer for average outside of the if else statement (float *average). And then only allocating memory in the if else statement. I mean there is no error generated when you do that.

Comment: @Haider Hum, I don't see how that might work. Be careful with that pointer - how do you handle stack allocation? You can't set the pointer to a stack-allocated array inside the `if` and then use it after the `if` - you'll be accessing invalid memory because the array is not in scope anymore. It may work as expected, but it's still UB.

Comment: I am skeptical of that approach as well. Since I declare a float pointer and then (potentially) stack allocate it inside the if statement. But it didn't generate an error so I asked.

Comment: @Haider Yeah, working as expected is a form of UB. But you really shouldn't be doing that. Nasty, unexpected things can happen.